# Create Database in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.1

At the moment, I have installed postGreSql 9.1 for windows with the extension of postGIS on it.

Now, I want to create a new Database in PostGIS.

Can someones guide me with an easy to follow and exact procedure on how to go about this, have gone through the documentation, but its too confusing.

Comment: Have you used databases or PostgreSQL before? If not, maybe you should start with the PostgreSQL tutorial, then go back to the PostGIS documentation once you've worked through some of the PostGIS basics.

Comment: No, i have not used PostgreSQL before, its my first attempt. Could you send me a good link to the some beginner PostgreSQL tutorials that also include PostGIS also in the Answer section below. Thanks for Your Help.. !!

Comment: What I would do to answer your request is: Search Google. So I'll get you to do that instead. The PostgreSQL tutorial is at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html . Read that first, then look for introductory PostGIS tutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create database:

```
createdb mygeodatabase
```

Add PostGIS functions to it (PostGIS 2.0, PostgreSQL 9.2):

```
psql mygeodatabase
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

With older PostGIS/PostgreSQL versions (your folders depend on OS):

```
psql -d mygeodatabase -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql
psql -d mygeodatabase -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```